# can you pass component props to mapGetters vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm starting to make a universal input vue component. Before I worry about changing the data in the input, I just wanted to get the initial value from the store.

I have something like this:

```
<template lang="html">
  <input class="input-text" type="text" name="" :value="value">
</template>

<script>
import store from '@/store/index';

export default {
  name: 'InputText',
  props: [
    'dataModel',
    'propertyName',
  ],
  computed: {
    value() {
      return store.state[this.dataModel][this.propertyName];
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This works. Instead of the `value` function in `computed`. I wanted to leverage `mapGetters`. So I tried something like this instead:

```
...mapGetters({
  value: `${this.dataModel}/${this.propertyName}`,
}),
```

As soon as I tried the latter I got `undefined` for both values `this.dataModel` and `this.propertyName`. The context of `this` changes when invoking `mapGetters` because were in a new object. Is there a way to pass component props into `mapGetters`? Is there a way to set the context of `this` to be the component rather than the object argument? Or was my original approach/another approach the correct way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First, don t import the store in components, its available as `this.$store`, so remove:

```
import store from '@/store/index';
```

You can't use `this` like you are in mapGetters because it doesn't exist in the context youre trying to use it yet. The component is still early in it's lifecycle when when setting up properties. As far as I know, the name must be defined beforehand.

Comment: I think you can't use `this` because you are within a new object's context, normally in a function block you can do `let self = this` solving this problem. What I'm wondering if there is *any* way you can pass component props to map getters

Comment: I don't think it's possible to assign a getter like that dynamically. I tried a while back and never did find a way, but that was several months ago. Something may have come along.

Comment: cool, that's good enough for me, I have a working solution and maybe I was just trying to over engineer the problem. Thanks!